# SQL SELECT to get the first N positive integers

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to get a result set containing the first N positive integers. Is it possible to use only standard SQL SELECT statement to get them (without any count table provided)?

If it's not possible, is there any specific MySQL way to achieve this?

Comment: First in what defintion?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Seems that what you want is a `dummy rowset`.

In `MySQL`, it's impossible without having a table.

Most major systems provide a way to do it:

- In `Oracle`:

  ```
  SELECT  level
  FROM    dual
  CONNECT BY
          level <= 10
  ```
- In `SQL Server`:

  ```
  WITH    q AS
          (
          SELECT  1 AS num
          UNION ALL
          SELECT  num + 1
          FROM    q
          WHERE   num < 10
          )
  SELECT  *
  FROM    q
  ```
- In `PostgreSQL`:

  ```
  SELECT  num
  FROM    generate_series(1, 10) num
  ```

`MySQL` lacks something like this and this is a serious drawback.

I wrote a simple script to generate test data for the sample tables in my blog posts, maybe it will be of use:

```
CREATE TABLE filler (
        id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
) ENGINE=Memory;

CREATE PROCEDURE prc_filler(cnt INT)
BEGIN
        DECLARE _cnt INT;
        SET _cnt = 1;
        WHILE _cnt <= cnt DO
                INSERT
                INTO    filler
                SELECT  _cnt;
                SET _cnt = _cnt + 1;
        END WHILE;
END
$$
```

You call the procedure and the table gets filled with the numbers.

You can reuse it during the duration of the session.

Comment: Great answer. This sure is helpful.

Answer (score 10):

A possible solution (admittedly not very elegant) is to use any table with a sufficiently large number of records.

For the first 10 integers (using the mysql.help_relation, but any table would do), you could use the following query:

```
SELECT  @N := @N +1 AS integers 
FROM mysql.help_relation , (SELECT @N:=0) dum LIMIT 10;
```

This could also be placed in a function taking Min and Max.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. successfully used the following to get a range of dates: `SELECT @i:=DATE_SUB(@i, INTERVAL 1 DAY) date FROM mysql.help_relation, (SELECT @i:=CURRENT_DATE) v WHERE @i > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 MONTH);`.

Comment: This is not a generic solution. It works, provided the table used has at least the amount of rows you want to get. Create a dummy table with no rows, and SELECT @N:=@N + 1 AS integers FROM dummy, (SELECT @N:=0) dum LIMIT 10 produces no rows.

Comment: Might be old, but this is awesome. I _knew_ something like this had to exist.

Answer (score 4):

Weird solution, but...

```
SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3....
```

Comment: this is not a solution

Answer (score 4):

The sequence I propose allows the programmer to execute the following query :

```
select value from sequence where value>=15 and value<100;
```

And to obtain the expected results : the sequence of integers between 15 (inclusive) and 100 (exclusive).

If that's what you want, you'll have to create the two following views, views that you'll declare only once :

```
create view digits as select 0 n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9;

create view sequence as select u.n+t.n*10+h.n*100 as value from digits as u cross join digits as t cross join digits as h;
```

This way you have your sequence with an intuitive SELECT...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Crazy!  ...and it works.  I needed something that worked in a view - using assignment into a variable is blocked for views.  Nice.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean retrieve them from a table, here N is 10, assuming intcolumn is the column with numbers in it.

```
SELECT intcolumn FROM numbers WHERE intcolumn > 0 LIMIT 10
```

**Edit**: In case you were actually looking to get the mathematical set of positive numbers without a table, I would reconsider, it can be intensive (depending on the implementation).  Commonly accepted practice seems to be to create a lookup table full of numbers, and then use the above query.

Comment: just change >= to > to get only positives.

Comment: Is 0 considered positive or negative?

Comment: I just checked, apparently the definition of positive numbers is greater than 0. Apparently zero is neither (according to wikipedia).

Comment: I guess the OP is asking for a way to do it without a table.

Comment: @Frank Bollack: I did consider it, but why bother doing it on the database at all in that case, you might as well just count upwards using code, surely?

Answer (score 1):

This may help

To obtain a random integer R in the range i <= R <  j, use the expression FLOOR(i  + RAND() * (j – i)). For example, to obtain a random integer in the range the range 7 <= R <  12, you could use the following statement:

`SELECT FLOOR(7 + (RAND() * 5));`

Comment: He is asking about sequential positive integers. Not about random.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that `N` is limited (and usually it is), you can use a construction such as:

```
select (a.digit + (10 * b.digit) + (100 * c.digit) + (1000 * d.digit) + (10000 * e.digit) + (100000 * f.digit)) as n
    from (select 0 as digit union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as digit union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as digit union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
    cross join (select 0 as digit union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d
    cross join (select 0 as digit union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as e
    cross join (select 0 as digit union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as f;
```

which will generate the first million numbers. If you need only the positive numbers, simply add `+ 1` to the expression.

Note that in MySQL in particular, the results may not be sorted. You need to append `order by n` to the end if you need ordered numbers. This will increase the execution time dramatically, though (on my machine, it jumped up from 5 ms to 500 ms).

For simple queries, here's a query for just the first 10000 numbers:

```
select (a.digit + (10 * b.digit) + (100 * c.digit) + (1000 * d.digit)) as n
    from (select 0 as digit union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as digit union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as digit union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
    cross join (select 0 as digit union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d;
```

This answer is adapted from the following query that returns a date range: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2157776/2948

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following SO questions:

- [How to generate a range of numbers in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers-in-mysql)
- [generate an integer sequence in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304461/generate-an-integer-sequence-in-mysql)

**Edit:**

Another aproach is to create a stored procedure that does that for you. PostgreSQL contains a function generate_series(start, stop) that does what you want.

```
select * from generate_series(2,4);
 generate_series
-----------------
               2
               3
               4
(3 rows)
```

I'm not familar with MySQL but somthing like that should be easy to implement, if you are okay with SPs.
[This](http://ondra.zizka.cz/stranky/programovani/sql/mysql_stored_procedures.texy#Utilities) site shows an implemetation.

Comment: It would appear as though both those methods require a lookup table of some form (using AUTO_INCREMENT)

Answer (score 0):

I' pretty sure that you cannot do it, if I understand your question correctly.

As I understand your question, you want the list, from a single SQL statement, without having to reference a specific table?

I'm pretty sure that it is not possible in any SQL dialect. If you were to get a sequentially incrementing number along with the results of another query, then that would be possible (depending on SQL dialect, on mssql it would be rownumber(), but I don't know how in MySql, but it's probably there)

But that's not what I hear you ask?

Comment: In PostgreSQL there is a function called generate_series(start, stop) that does exactly what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports analytic windowing functions the following is simple works really well:

```
SELECT  row_number() over (partition by 1 order by 1) numbers
FROM SOME_TABLE
LIMIT 2700;
```

This statement returns a set of numbers from 1 to 2700.