# Get value even if it doesn't exist in table from SQL SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, if-statement

I have a MySQL table that looks something like this:

```
|---ID---|---COUNTER---|
|   1    |      2      |
|   2    |      6      |
|   3    |      1      |
|   5    |      9      |
|   6    |      10     |
```

I'm looking for a SELECT statement that returns ID's and their COUNTER. The table only have ID's such as: 1,2,3,5,6. Is there a statement where you say: I want ID's 1 to 10 even if they doesn't exist in the table, and if the ID doesn't exist, return the ID anyway with the COUNTER value 0. For example:

```
|---ID---|---COUNTER---|
|   1    |      2      |
|   2    |      6      |
|   3    |      1      |
|   4    |      0      |
|   5    |      9      |
|   6    |      10     |
|   7    |      0      |
|   8    |      0      |
|   9    |      0      |
|   10   |      0      |
```

Do I have to create a SELECT statement that contains NOT EXIST parameters?

Thanks in advance, Steve-O

Comment: The database can't return an ID that does not exist, because it can't know it should. Do you have another table defining what valid values are?

Comment: @Jan Hudec: no, and I know it's stupid that I don't have one. But, is there some way I can accomplish my goal with LEFT JOIN?

Comment: "I want ID's 1 to 10" -- where is the range 1 to 10 definied? e.g. in a table? passed in as parameters?

Comment: I was just putting it out there as an example. Thanks to Michal Powaga solution, the range is from the lowest ID to the highest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without creating a temp table:

```
select t.num as id, coalesce(yt.counter, 0)
from your_table yt
right join (
    select 1 as num union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union
    select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 10
) t on yt.id = t.num
order by t.num
```

and bit more general:

```
select t.num as id, coalesce(yt.counter, 0)
from your_table yt
right join (
    select t1.num + t2.num * 10 + t3.num * 100 as num
    from (
        select 1 as num union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union
        select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 0
    ) t1
    cross join (
        select 1 as num union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union
        select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 0
    ) t2
    cross join (
        select 1 as num union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union
        select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 0
    ) t3
) t on yt.id = t.num
where t.num between (select min(id) from your_table) and (select max(id) from your_table)
```

You can define limit by yourself here I've used `min` and `max` of `id` value from `your_table`.

Comment: Should I replace 'y' and 'yt' with my tablename, too?

Comment: @Steve-O `yt` is an alias only so you can leave as is (or change if you don't like it). Only `your_table` change to proper table name and if columns are correct this should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `left join` to solve your issue. Read more about `left join` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: There are different ways of doing same thing in sql, I had given one of the approach.

Comment: -1 : Downvoter please comment. If @onedaywhen you have done it, please let me know if is this incorrect answer.

Comment: I didn't say "should", "will" is suggestion and "should" is compulsory. Anyways updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very robust, but if you created a temporary table with the ID's you wanted in it, you could then left join to your table containing ID and Counter which would include all the values:

```
Declare @tempidtable as table ( imaginaryid int )

insert into @tempidtable ( imaginaryid ) values ( 1 )
insert into @tempidtable ( imaginaryid ) values ( 2 )
insert into @tempidtable ( imaginaryid ) values ( 3 )

select 
@temptable.imaginaryid,
ISNULL(yourothertable.counter, 0)
from @tempidtable
left join yourothertable
on @tempidtable.imaginaryid = yourothertable.id
```

As Tomek says you could loop over the inserts to make it easier to maintain, or possible store the ids you want as a base in another table, using this as the basis for the join rather than a temp table.

Answer (score 2):

Create a table with all possible ID's:

```
create table Numbers (nr int primary key);

declare i int default 1;

while i < 100000 do
    insert into Numbers (nr) values (i);
    set i = i + 1;
end while;
```

Then you can use `left join` to return all numbers:

```
select  n.NR
,       c.Counter
from    Numbers n
left join
        Counters c
on      c.ID = n.NR
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to create (generate in loop) temporary table with the complete sequence of numbers from 1 to N (where N is the MAX(Id) of counted table). Then do left join to that table and apply GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

You need the range of integers to do an outer join with your table based on ID. Generating a range of integers is dependent on the SQL vendor if you do not want to use a temporary table. See [SQL SELECT to get the first N positive integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475973/sql-select-to-get-the-first-n-positive-integers) for hints on how to do this based on your SQL vendor.