# Add rows in mysql result when specific value does not exist

Tags: mysql

I am trying to modify MySQL output results.

```
Select number_purchases, COUNT(number_purchases) as user_count
FROM user_order
GROUP BY number_purchases
ORDER BY number_purchases ASC
```

so I get the number of purchases in the first column and the number of users that made that number of purchases in the second column.

I would like to modify the result a bit. I need a function around those lines:

> If npb = 1, 2, 3... to 10 does not exist, add line with the missing
>   npb and a corresponding user_count = 0

Comment: Why do you want to do this in SQL?  Surely your application code can handle this eventuality (i.e. if record is missing from results, it is known to have 0 users)?

Comment: Hey. I am not trying to do it in mysql. I am actually trying to do it in vba. But, If I get mysql query to change then My VBA code would work. I am still a beginner. I asked a similar question for vba but did not get any feedback so i am trying this way

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it would be to create a view with all the numbers and left join and then use group by. but according to [SQL SELECT to get the first N positive integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475973/sql-select-to-get-the-first-n-positive-integers) , you will have to create a table though.