# Find minimum non-used value from collection of rows marked with an id and customId

Tags: mysql, sql, minimum

I already saw a similar question here([Get minimum unused value in MySQL column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719690/get-minimum-unused-value-in-mysql-column)) which is exactly what I want except what I need to select the minimum available number not from just a table but from rows with specific customId as well.
In case the other question gets removed or something, here is what query is needed:

In case of rows `[1,2,3]` the query should return **4**.

In case of rows `[2,3,4]` the query should return **1**.

In case of rows `[1,3,4]` the query should return **2**.

In case of multiple missing rows `[1,2,4,6,7]` the query should return minimum missing value **3**.

I tried solutions showed in the first linked question and from this one as well link([SQL - Find the lowest unused number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817300/sql-find-the-lowest-unused-number)). I tried tweaking them to include customId in WHERE clauses but the queries is too advanced and confusing for me, so it did not work. I have tried doing this:

```
  SELECT min(unused) AS unused
  FROM (
  SELECT MIN(t1.id)+1 as unused
  FROM yourTable AS t1
  WHERE t1.customId = ? AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM yourTable AS t2 WHERE t2.customId = ? 
   AND t2.id = t1.id+1)
  UNION
  -- Special case for missing the first row
  SELECT 1
  FROM DUAL
    WHERE customId = ? AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE id = 1)

  )AS subquery
```

But it shows access or syntax violation error.

Comment: Where is the `customId` column in your examples? You don't show anything different from the previous questions.

Comment: You say you tried tweaking the other answers to do what you want. Show what you tried.

Comment: @barmar I described the role of customId before showing the examples. I will update for some examples of what I have attempted

Comment: More details are needed. What if there's a gap in the ID sequence with the custom ID, but it's filled in with a row that doesn't have that custom ID? Show example data that has both columns, and the desired result.

Comment: I don't get a syntax error when I replace `?` with an ID number. When you have a placeholder in the query, you have to prepare it, not use it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked one of the queries I found on the web until it worked... Obviously it is not neccesarily fast or perfomant but it work, so here it goes:

```
SELECT min(unused) AS unused FROM
  ( SELECT MIN(t1.group_number)+1 as unused FROM units AS t1 WHERE t1.user_id = '.$ai_id.' AND 
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM units AS t2 WHERE t2.user_id = '.$ai_id.' AND t2.group_number= 
   t1.group_number +1) UNION
    -- Special case for missing the first row 
    SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM units  WHERE  group_number= 1 
    AND user_id = '.$ai_id.') )AS subquery
```

I am not sure how exactly it works, but it somehow does, I can only get the outlines...
The `user_id` in this case is the aforementioned `customId` and `unit_group_number` is the column used to search for missing "hole" value which will be returned as `unused`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select 1 + min(col)
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col = t.col + 1);
```

If you need to include "1", then:

```
select (case when min(tt.mincol) <> 1 then 1
             else 1 + min(col)
        end)
from t cross join
     (select min(col) as mincol from t) tt
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col = t.col + 1)
```

Comment: This answer doesn't show how to include the additional condition on the `customId` column.