# Combining JSON_SEARCH and JSON_EXTRACT get me: "Invalid JSON path expression."

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-5.7

I have a table names "campaigns". One of the columns is named "filter_apps" and his type is **JSON**

I have file rows and they just contain array of tokens like so:

```
["be3beb1fe916ee653ab825fd8fe022", "c130b917983c719495042e31306ffb"]
["4fef3f1999c78cf987960492da4d2a"]
["106c274e319bdeae8bcf8daf515b1f"]
["2521f0df6cffb7487d527319674cf3"]
["c130b917983c719495042e31306ffb"]
```

Examples:

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(filter_apps, 'one', 'c130b917983c719495042e31306ffb') FROM campaigns;
```

Result:

```
"$[1]"
null
null
null
"$[0]"
```

Right now everything is correct, the matched columns come back. If I make a test I can prove it:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(filter_apps, '$[1]') FROM campaigns;
```

Result

```
"c130b917983c719495042e31306ffb"
null
null
null
null
```

So at this point I think I can extract the values using JSON_EXTRACT, my query:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(filter_apps, JSON_SEARCH(filter_apps, 'one', 'c130b917983c719495042e31306ffb')) FROM campaigns;
```

That leads me to an error:

"[42000][3143] Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 1."

Comment: After digging a little more a found the solution, I just wrap JSON_SEARCH in a JSON_UNQUOTE method!

Answer (score 15):

> **SOLUTION**

Simple as that:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(filter_apps, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(filter_apps, 'one', 'c130b917983c719495042e31306ffb'))) FROM campaigns;
```

Problem resolved! I wrap JSON_SEARCH in a JSON_UNQUOTE method!

A little tip, I found the solution here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html

Comment: Great question.
I did the same here and worked like a charm. Unfortunately, I found this question only after already solved here by myself. On my case, additionally, I had to use a `REPLACE` function together to change last part of the returned "path" from `JSON_SEARCH`.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for this response. I had struggled with this for MONTHS and MONTHS and not found the solution to this.  I even read in multiple places that using variables as the path expression was not permitted.  This is a huge discovery that helps working with JSON in MySQL (particularly versions below MySQL 8).  Thanks again!

Comment: Just curious what trick can be done to pass results from JSON_SEARCH to JSON_EXTRACT when `all` search mode instead of `one` is used.

Comment: thanks! a little counter intuitive (on MySQL's part); I'd just tried JSON_QUOTE before giving up and coming here.

Comment: Even I am curious to know what is the workaround if we use all instead of one.
example: 
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(filter_apps, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(filter_apps, 'all', 'c130b917983c719495042e31306ffb'))) FROM campaigns;

Answer (score 1):

It took me hours, as my JSON object is way more complex, but I found the solution for the 'all' option.

```
SELECT *,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(filter_apps, ',', n), ',', -1)), '[', ''), ']', '') AS all_json
FROM (
    SELECT *, JSON_EXTRACT(filter_apps, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(filter_apps, 'all', 'c130b917983c719495042e31306ffb'))) AS hit
    FROM campaigns
) AS t
JOIN (SELECT  @N := @N +1 AS n FROM campaigns, (SELECT @N:=0) dum LIMIT 10) numbers
      ON CHAR_LENGTH(filter_apps) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(filter_apps, ',', '')) >= n - 1
WHERE hit IS NOT NULL;
    
# for the "JOIN-FROM" use a table that has more or equal entries than the length of your longest JSON array
# make sure the "JOIN-LIMIT" is higher or equal than the length of your longest JSON array
```

Query Explanation:

1. Inner SELECT:
   Main Select as asked in question with JSON_SEARCH Option 'all'
2. JOIN:
   a) SELECT table 'numbers':
   create a table which contains the numbers from 1 to user defined LIMIT.
   compare [SQL SELECT to get the first N positive integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475973/sql-select-to-get-the-first-n-positive-integers)
   b) JOIN ON combined with Outer SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX:
   splits the defined array column 'filter_apps' to the number of element of the array. Note user defined limit of 2)a) must be equal or greater than the longest array to split. compare [SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)
3. REPLACE and LTRIM of Outer SELECT:
   used to remove remaining brackets and spaces of previous array
4. WHERE clause:
   to show only matching results of Inner SELECT

Comment: Please explain how it works with your solution so that people can easily understand it.