# MySQL 8 search JSON key by value in array

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-8.0

I've got MySQL table with JSON field, where I store data in such a format.

```
{
  "fields": {
    "1": {
      "s": "y"
    },
    "2": {
      "s": "n"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to obtain the keys in `fields`, e.g. 1 or 2 given the value of `s`.

Example query:

```
create table mytable ( mycol json );

insert into mytable set mycol = '{"fields": {"1": {"s": "y"},"2": {"s": "n"}}}';


select j.* from mytable, JSON_TABLE(mycol,
'$.fields.*' COLUMNS (
    json_key VARCHAR(10) PATH '$',
    s VARCHAR(10) PATH '$.s'
  )
) AS j where j.s = 'y';
```

gives:

```
# json_key, s
null, y
```

I would expect to get

```
# json_key, s
1, y
```

Is it possible to get that data somehow?

I don't need the results in `row` / `table` format. I would be happy to get the comma separated list of IDs (json_keys) meeting my criterium.

EDIT:
I was also thinking about getting the paths using `JSON_SEARCH` and passing that to `JSON_EXTRACT`, this was achieved here: [Combining JSON_SEARCH and JSON_EXTRACT get me: "Invalid JSON path expression."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540720/combining-json-search-and-json-extract-get-me-invalid-json-path-expression)
Unfortunately the difference is that I would need to use `JSON_SEARCH` in `all` mode, as I need all results. In such a mode `JSON_SEARCH` returns list of paths, where as `JSON_EXTRACT` accepts list of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `FOR ORDINALITY` (see [12.17.6 JSON Table Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html)), this type enumerates rows in the COLUMNS clause:

```sql
SELECT
  JSON_UNQUOTE(
    JSON_EXTRACT(
      JSON_KEYS(`mycol` ->> '$.fields'),
      CONCAT('$[', `j`.`row` - 1, ']')
    )
  ) `json_key`,
  `j`.`s`
FROM
  `mytable`,
  JSON_TABLE(
    `mycol`,
    '$.fields.*' COLUMNS (
      `row` FOR ORDINALITY,
      `s` VARCHAR(10) PATH '$.s'
  )
) `j`
WHERE
  `j`.`s` = 'y';
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=92462ffb9bc13b0368ad71024bc67708).