# Complex MySQL query it is

Tags: mysql

I have an `answers` **table** (ans_id, question_id , ans_date) and an `answers_votes` **table** (vote_id , user_id , ans_id , vote = 1 or -1).

How do I select from answers that have the big **sum(vote)** of votes that posted today. This means have todays date in **ans_date**.

Comment: Hmm... second question like this today.  Homework perhaps?
What have you tried thus far?  Here's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553776/mysql-join-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.ans_id
     , a.question_id
     , a.ans_date
     , (select sum(vote) from answers_votes where ans_id = a.ans_id) as points
     , (select count(*) from answers_votes where ans_id = a.ans_id and vote = 1) as up_votes
     , (select count(*) from answers_votes where ans_id = a.ans_id and vote = -1) as down_votes
  from answers a
 where date(a.ans_date) = date(now())
 order by points desc
```

Although this now makes the `points` value somewhat redundant.  It could be calculated just the same as doing `up_votes - down_votes` - provided a vote is always worth only 1 point up or down.

Comment: can you count ans that toke -1 and ans that toke 1

Comment: please help me to know the number of -1 vots and 1

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
select answers.ans_id, count(*) as nb_votes
from answers
    inner join answers_votes on answers_votes.ans_id = answers.ans_id
where answers.ans_date = curdate()
group by answers.ans_id
order by count(*) desc
limit 10
```

should give you the 10 answers that have the most votes, and have been created today.

If you want more, or less, than 10, you can change the value in the `limit` clause.

*Not tested, as I don't have your database -- so might contain a few mistakes...*

Comment: Using COUNT(answers_votes) for the aggregate function will give you the number of votes. Use SUM(answers_votes.vote) to get the weight of the vote since answers_votes.vote can be +1 or -1.