# Select range of numbers?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate a range of numbers in Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers-in-mysql)

Is it possible to write a select statement that will return a list of numbers? Like

```
col_a  col_b
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
```

I can get one row by doing `SELECT 1, 1` but how do I get more? I'm thinking something like `SELECT range(1,10), range(1,10)` or `SELECT @x, @x FROM @x in range(1,10)`... I don't really know. Not sure if this is possible.

Yes, I know this is better suited for a different language, but I need to do it in MySQL.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to have this data put in a temporary table? What is the context of this "select range" query - does it need to be nested in something larger? Does it need to all happen in a single statement?

Comment: @jwd: Has to be done in one query, preferably no temporary table. The query gets passed to some PHP which loops over the results and puts it into a `<select>`. Normally this would pull from a table of options, but I just want to generate a list of dates, say 1961-2011 (-50 years to now).

Comment: nice, the crossjoin one is genius! :D

Answer (score 2):

One really stupid way:

```
SELECT 1,1 
UNION 
SELECT 2,2
....
SELECT 10,10
```

Comment: `FROM SomeTableDOesntMatter` is not even necessary here

Comment: I got an error when I tried it without, but it was an online tester. This one: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp

Comment: I've just tried on my localhost in MySQL 5.1.36 and it works without FROM caluse

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done by creating a TEMPORARY table (often using MEMORY engine) and selecting from it.

---

Added: Another way might be to create a stored procedure that will create a prepared statement similar to what cularis propses in his answer.