# Codeigniter query to data from database for each day

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a `$from date` and `$to date` with me so I want to fetch four values from the the database for days in between `$from` and `$to` and including `$from` and `$to` . If the data does not exist for a day in the database  then zero must in placed as the value for the missing values.

So how would I write a query in codeigniter to make it happen and the corresponding date should be stored in the result for a particular row .

Comment: I think this question will give you a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range

Comment: What is the structure of your database table? do you have a record for each date even if does not have the wanted values?

Comment: No, I don't have each date in my record

Comment: and the date, in what format it is stored in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous solution is that I using PHP to check and set zero for missing date. But I have some new solutions and you can try

1. Create a table to store dates and left/right join with your table
2. Or create temporary table using stored procedure and join. Temporary will be auto deleted when a session is expired
3. Using UNION with select statement

There're many answers on StackOverflow
[MySQL how to fill missing dates in range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range)
[MySQL group by date and count including missing dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804531/mysql-group-by-date-and-count-including-missing-dates)
[Running total over date range - fill in the missing dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381915/running-total-over-date-range-fill-in-the-missing-dates)
[MySQL to fill in missing dates when using GROUP BY DATE(table.timestamp) without joining on temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844486/mysql-to-fill-in-missing-dates-when-using-group-by-datetable-timestamp-without)

Comment: Minh Quy I get you but i don't want to create a table for it I want use the exisiting database .I don't have each date in my database.

Comment: I see your problem. You can create temporary table to store each date between `$from` and `$to` date. Second way, you can use for loop PHP to create UNION statement and concat with normal statement. Or using my stupid solution, using PHP to check missing date when you print/echo your result

Comment: hahaha ..! Total satisfied with your answer. I will be using the second way not the stupid solution but it is also right. This first  I wish that I have chance to upvote a person 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

i think you solution needs to be actually in PHP and not sure if you can get what you are looking for directly from MYSQL just by a query. As from what i understand you want to run a query, get all records that are in your defined date range and then have dates that has no records have an empty row (or with any other value you decide...).

I would actually run the same query you have for selecting rows between the daterange and use [DatePeriod Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) to generate an array of all days between the start and end dates.

```
$begin = new DateTime( '2012-08-01' );
$end = new DateTime( '2012-10-31' );
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' );

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d") . "<br>";
}
```

With this we will be able to run over each day from the `$from_date` to the `$end_date`.

Next we will need to go other the rows from the DB and see on which days there are records and where no according the the `daterange` object we have.

Here is an approach that would work i believe, it's not the cleanest sample but some additional work on it and you can make it a bit prettier, but i think that will work for what you need.

The Database section in the code is not in Codeigniter but as it is only getting a simple query you should not have any trouble changing that.

```
// set the start & end dates
$from_date = '2012-09-11';
$to_date     = '2012-11-11';

// create a daterange object
$begin         = new DateTime($from_date);
$end           = new DateTime($to_date );
$end            = $end->modify( '+1 day' );
$interval      = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT col1, dateCol from tb WHERE dateCol>'".$from_date."' AND dateCol<'".$to_date."' order by dateCol ");
$sth->execute(); 
$rows = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$rowsByDay = array(); // will hold the rows with date keys

// loop on results to create thenew rowsByDay
foreach($rows as $key=>$row) {
    $rowsByDay[strtotime($row['dateCol'])][] = $row; // add the row to the new rows array with a timestamp key
}

// loop of the daterange elements and fill the rows array 
foreach($daterange as $date){
    if(!isset($rowsByDay[strtotime($date->format("Y-m-d"))])) // if element does not exists - meaning no record for a specific day
    {
        $rowsByDay[strtotime($date->format("Y-m-d"))] = array(); // add an empty arra (or anything else)
    }
}

// sort the rowsByDay array so they all are arrange by day from start day to end day
ksort($rowsByDay); 


// just for showing what we get at the end for rowsByDay array
foreach ($rowsByDay as $k=>$v) {
    echo date('Y-m-d',$k);
    var_dump($v);
    echo '<hr/>';
}
```

Hope this gets you on the right way...

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps,

```
$this->db->where('date_column >= ',$date_given_start);
$this->db->where('date_column <= ',$date_given_end);
$this->db->get('TABLE_NAME')->result();


// if column is datetime
$this->db->where('DATE(date_column) >= ',$date_given_start);
$this->db->where('DATE(date_column) <= ',$date_given_end);
$this->db->get('TABLE_NAME')->result();
```

Comment: Excuse, I have already know the query you have written but it would not return zero value for the missing day in the database . So please read my question carefully and answer it.