# Need help to build a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with following schema

**Sample table**

```
email        |  name  |  address 
1@gmail.com  |  A     |  CA
```

I want the same set of record with five different static email addresses

**Expected output**

```
email              |   name   |   address
static1@gmail.com  |   A      |   CA
static2@gmail.com  |   A      |   CA
static3@gmail.com  |   A      |   CA
static4@gmail.com  |   A      |   CA
static5@gmail.com  |   A      |   CA
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you really need to do it on the SQL side?

Comment: What dbms you used? MSSQL? Oracle? DB2? PostgreSQL? MySQL?

Comment: Preferably Mysql ... as i am working on an internal tool which is quite similar to it

Comment: Yes, it is possible! Take a look at this answer: [Generating a range of numbers in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/186756/1765658)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT CONCAT('static', @n := @n + 1, '@', SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1)) email,
       `name`,
       address
  FROM table1 CROSS JOIN  
       INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS JOIN
       (SELECT @n := 0) n
 LIMIT 5
```

Output:

```
|             EMAIL | NAME | ADDRESS |
--------------------------------------
| static1@gmail.com |    A |      CA |
| static2@gmail.com |    A |      CA |
| static3@gmail.com |    A |      CA |
| static4@gmail.com |    A |      CA |
| static5@gmail.com |    A |      CA |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fc7a/20)**

Comment: yeah this does it, but it sounds like you just gave a spammer a solution to generate a bunch of emails.