# Iterating thought dates in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, iteration

I have a table 1 of data that looks a bit like that:

```
Record# Date        Person
1       12/12/2012  Tom
2       01/02/2013  Tom
3       10/02/2013  Tom
4       02/01/2013  John
5       04/01/2014  John
6       30/06/2010  Mary
7       30/06/2011  Mary
8       30/06/2012  Mary
9       30/07/2012  Mary
```

and another table 2 where we have the registration date of each Person

```
Person  RegisterDate   MaxRecord
Tom     15/12/2011     100
John    01/01/2013     10
Mary    16/06/2010     50
```

Before adding a record in the table1, I need to check whether the annual count of record (table1) by Person is lower than the MaxRecord number (table2) for that Person. By Annual, I mean startDate = registration date and endDate =  registration date + 1 year and not from Januray 1st till December 31st.

If I want to add a record for Mary, I want to write SQL that will give me the following output:

```
StartDate   EndDate     CountRecord
16/06/2010  15/06/2011    1
16/06/2011  15/06/2012    1
16/06/2012  15/06/2013    2
```

Once this output is build, I could test whether thedate of a new record (for a Person) is allowed or not.

Could someone give me a clue, a link to a tutorial or some help please?

Answer (score 0):

For the following I am assuming you already have a numbers table, If you don't have a numbers table, then I'd recommend you make one then, but if you don't want to then you can [create a number list on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/generating-a-range-of-numbers-in-mysql)

You can get a list of all boundaries by cross joining your table of Register dates (RegDate) with your numbers table:

```
SELECT  r.Person, 
        DATE_ADD(r.RegisterDate, INTERVAL n.Number YEAR) PeriodStart,
        DATE_ADD(r.RegisterDate, INTERVAL n.Number + 1 YEAR) PeriodEnd,
        n.Number
FROM    RegDate r
        CROSS JOIN Numbers n;
```

This gives a table like (Just for Tom and adding `WHERE n.Number <= 3;` as an example):

```
Person  PERIODSTART   PERIODEND   NUMBER
Tom     15/12/2011    15/12/2012    0
Tom     15/12/2012    15/12/2013    1
Tom     15/12/2013    15/12/2014    2
Tom     15/12/2014    15/12/2015    3
```

[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b66a/2)

You then need to join this to your table of other dates (T) to do the count:

```
SELECT  r.Person,
        DATE_ADD(r.RegisterDate, INTERVAL n.Number YEAR) StartDate,
        DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(r.RegisterDate, INTERVAL n.Number + 1 YEAR), INTERVAL -1 DAY) EndDate,
        COUNT(T.Record) AS `CountRecord`
FROM    RegDate r
        CROSS JOIN Numbers n
        LEFT JOIN T
            ON T.Person = r.Person
            AND T.Date >= DATE_ADD(r.RegisterDate, INTERVAL n.Number YEAR)
            AND T.Date < DATE_ADD(r.RegisterDate, INTERVAL n.Number + 1 YEAR)
WHERE   DATE_ADD(r.RegisterDate, INTERVAL n.Number YEAR) <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
AND     r.Person = 'Mary'
GROUP BY r.Person, R.RegisterDate, n.Number;
```

Giving a final result of:

```
PERSON  STARTDATE   ENDDATE     COUNTRECORD
Mary    2010-06-16  2011-06-15      1
Mary    2011-06-16  2012-06-15      2
Mary    2012-06-16  2013-06-15      1
Mary    2013-06-16  2014-06-15      0
```

**[Full Example on SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df7ea6/2)**

*I have limited the results to where the StartDate is less than today using this line*

```
WHERE   DATE_ADD(r.RegisterDate, INTERVAL n.Number YEAR) <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

*you can obviously change this as you need*

Comment: Hello, I come back to ask something. So far i was using a numbered list cretaed on the fly. But now, I'd like to optimize the db and use a numbers table as you have suggested. The issue is when i use that numbered table, the sql result is empty!!! don't know why. Here is the sql script

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ass_numbers` (
  `SeqValue` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Contenu de la table `ass_numbers`
--

INSERT INTO `ass_numbers` (`SeqValue`) VALUES
(0),
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6),
(7),
(8),
(9),
(10);