# How to add multiple product_ids against single category_id in single query

Tags: mysql

I have a table ->
    table_product_categories - "product_id", "category_id"

I want to add multiple product ids (that are in range) against each category. How can i do that?

I am using:

```
insert into table_product_categories values (11, 1);
insert into table_product_categories values (12, 1);
insert into table_product_categories values (13, 1);
```

Is there any way where we can achieve the same in single query?

Devesh

Answer (score 1):

You can't generate sequence numbers in MySQL. You could use a temporary table with sequence numbers to achieve that

```
insert into table_product_categories 
select seq_num, 1
from your_temp_table
where seq_num between 11 and 30
order by seq_num asc
```

Comment: I know this approach. but even here i need to mention (11, 1),
       (12, 1),
       (13, 1);  But since product_id is in range, there must be a way where i can mention add product_id  =11to30 in category_id = 1

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple rows in single query.

`insert into table_product_categories values (11, 1), (12,1), (13,1);`

To add range you should iterate to that range and make a string like `(11, 1), (12,1), (13,1)`. Then execute a query.

Comment: Don't know it will be helpful or not! But you should look at here http://stackoverflow.com/q/186756/631652