# get the each value in between when only have the limit values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table that has a `week_start` and week_end column, both INTs. They are between 1-52 for the weeks of the year. Is it possible to list all the weeks in between `week_end` and `week_start`?

Comment: you could take a look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/generating-a-range-of-numbers-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you have a `week` field (not a `week_start` and `week_end` fields) in the database.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE week BETWEEN week_start AND week_end
```