# MySQL Loop Variable in a Query

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

I want to use the loop index "i" in the result of my select statement in order to insert it into another table. Is is like:

```
set i=0;
while i<25 do

    insert into a (x,y,z)
    select a,b,i
    from table1;

    set i= i+1;
end while;
```

What is the way to do it?

Comment: Do you want to insert all rows of table1 ? is there some where condition ? maybe you can post a real sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOne :)

I have just created variable i as @i and it is all solved.

Like this:

```
set @i=0;
while @i<25 do

    insert into a (x,y,z)
    select a,b,@i
    from table1;

    set @i= @i+1;
end while;
```

thx anyway :)

Comment: FYI, this will be incredibly slow. You should use a set-based approach.

Comment: Any samples that I can use?

Comment: Yes, [create a numbers table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/187410/679449) then join to it.

Answer (score 0):

Open the table separately asa  cursor, put fields in to variables, then use those variables and i to insert data in to the table with a

```
insert into a (x,y,z) values (var1, var2, i).
```

What you have written would put multiple rows in to a table a with each value of i.

Comment: Would u please explain a little bit more? I am new in mysql and did not understand this answer...