# Duplicate records of a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has approximately 4 million records. I would like to make it have 240 million like so:

1. Add an additional column of type BIGINT,
2. Import 59 times the data I already have,
3. And for each 4 million group of records, have the additional column to have a different value

The value of the additional column would come from another table.

So I have these records (except that I have 4 millions of them and not just 3):

```
| id | value |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 123   |
| 2  | 456   |
| 3  | 789   |
```

And I want to achieve this (except that I want 60 copies and not just 3):

```
| id | value | data |
+----+-------+------+
| 1  | 123   | 1    |
| 2  | 456   | 1    |
| 3  | 789   | 1    |
| 4  | 123   | 2    |
| 5  | 456   | 2    |
| 6  | 789   | 2    |
| 7  | 123   | 3    |
| 8  | 456   | 3    |
| 9  | 789   | 3    |
```

I tried to export my data (using `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE ...`), then re-import it (using `LOAD DATA INFILE ...`) but it is really painfully slow.

Is there a fast way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Create a new table where `id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` then just run this sixty times?   `INSERT INTO new_table (value, data) SELECT value, id FROM old_table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you'd like to take the `cartesian product` of 2 tables and create a new table since you say `The value of the additional column would come from another table`?  If so, something like this should work:

```
create table yourtable (id int, value int);
create table yournewtable (id int, value int, data int);
create table anothertable (data int);

insert into yourtable values (1, 123), (2, 456), (3, 789);
insert into anothertable values (1), (2), (3);

insert into yournewtable
select t.id, t.value, a.data
from yourtable t, anothertable a
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/525bf6/1)

Results:

```
ID  VALUE DATA
1   123   1
2   456   1
3   789   1
1   123   2
2   456   2
3   789   2
1   123   3
2   456   3
3   789   3
```

---

Edit, Side Note -- it looks like your ID field in your new table is not suppose to keep repeating the same ids?  If so, you can use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field instead.  However, this could mess up the original rows if they aren't sequential.

Comment: Those results don't match the ops results

Comment: @MatBailie -- just sample data :)

Comment: Thank you @sgeddes, I didn't know that what I wanted was called "cartesion product". I have marked your answer as accepted, but I could not run your query on my DB because my machine doesn't have enough RAM.

So I did this: 
`insert into yournewtable
select t.id, t.value, a.data
from yourtable t, 1`

then

`insert into yournewtable
select t.id, t.value, a.data
from yourtable t, 2`
and so on until I couldn't anymore.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend that you create a new table.  You can do this using a `cross join`:

```
create table WayBigTable as 
    select t.*, n
    from table t cross join
         (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
         . . .
          select 60
         ) n;
```

I'm not sure why you would want a `bigint` for this column.  If you really need that, you can cast to `unsigned`.

Comment: Are you sure that a single transaction of 240 million rows would be better than 60 transactions of 4 million rows?

Comment: @MatBailie It'll surely be faster than 60 outfiles.

Comment: @MatBailie . . . I don't actually know for MySQL.  For a new table with a single transaction, there is no need to log the inserts (the table can just be deleted if the statement fails).  I don't know if MySQL has this optimization, but it would be in `create table as` instead of in `insert`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. You need a cross join of your table with a range. Something in a line of this:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,value,data) SELECT id, value from table 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION ... SELECT 60) AS data;
```

Use this answer [Generating a range of numbers in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/generating-a-range-of-numbers-in-mysql) as reference on number range.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,value INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1  ,123),
(2  ,456),
(3  ,789);

ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN data INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+-------+------+
| id | value | data |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 |   123 |    1 |
|  2 |   456 |    1 |
|  3 |   789 |    1 |
+----+-------+------+


SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

INSERT INTO my_table SELECT NULL,value,data+i2.i*10+i1.i+1 FROM my_table,ints i1,ints i2;


SELECT * FROM my_table;
+-----+-------+------+
| id  | value | data |
+-----+-------+------+
|  1  |   123 |    1 |
|  2  |   456 |    1 |
|  3  |   789 |    1 |
|  4  |   123 |    2 |
|  5  |   456 |    2 |
|  6  |   789 |    2 |
|  7  |   123 |    3 |
|  8  |   456 |    3 |
...
... 
| 296 |   456 |   97 |
| 297 |   789 |   97 |
| 298 |   123 |   98 |
| 299 |   456 |   98 |
| 300 |   789 |   98 |
| 301 |   123 |   99 |
| 302 |   456 |   99 |
| 303 |   789 |   99 |
+-----+-------+------+
303 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note, for 240 million rows, this is still going to be a bit slow :-(