# Repeat a result row multiple times by value in row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, syntax, repeat

i have a question about sql query.
i want to duplicate a one row with same value, 
The number of lines must be same with the value of quantity

example i have 1 data like this

```
Item  ItemName   Quantity
B100  Mouse      10
```

but i want to be like this

```
Item  ItemName   Quantity
B100  Mouse      10
B100  Mouse      10
B100  Mouse      10
B100  Mouse      10
B100  Mouse      10
B100  Mouse      10
B100  Mouse      10
B100  Mouse      10
B100  Mouse      10
B100  Mouse      10
```

can you help me

Thanks Before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `numbers` table and just do a `CROSS JOIN` with it

```
select Item , ItemName ,  Quantity
from yourtable A
cross join (select num from numbers) b
where a.Quantity <= b.num
```

To generate sequential numbers in `Mysql` check the below answers

- [generate an integer sequence in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304461/generate-an-integer-sequence-in-mysql)
- [Generating a range of numbers in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/generating-a-range-of-numbers-in-mysql)

Comment: Thankyou, very usefull
But i think where condition shoul be 
"where a.Quantity >= b.num"