# How to split a row into many equals rows by a value in a column in MySql?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

MySQL Sample **Order** Table (Click to see the table):

[MySQL **Order** Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDhil.png)

I search everywhere however unable to find some MySQL syntax/query to get the below result. 
MySQL query result needed(Click to see the result table):

[MySQL query needed result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGxnx.png)

Looking for MySQL query which will provide the above result.

Comment: Try to write some code and ask question about bug in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeat a result row multiple times by value in row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253461/repeat-a-result-row-multiple-times-by-value-in-row)