# can i create 100 rows with IDs from 1 to 100 without inserting them one by one?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id     status
1        0
2        0
3        0
4        0
5        0
.
.
100      0
```

This should be the format. i need to create id and status column putting 1 to 100 in id and zero in status. i would like to know is there any way i can create it with query or i have to do it manually

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating a range of numbers in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/generating-a-range-of-numbers-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```
select  @i:=@i+1 as id
       ,0        as status

from    mysql.help_keyword,(select @i:=0) t

limit   100
;
```