# Return result in SQL even if one of the where clause is not met

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my problem. I have an SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE week_no >= 1 AND week_no <= 5
```

But the result only returns the following result.

```
Col1 | Col2 | Week_No
 A      B       1
 C      D       2
 D      E       4
 F      G       5
```

I tried pushing to the array result of the query the "week_no" #3 with default values but it seems it doesn't work.

I would like to know if there's a much easier way in doing it on SQL? Like inserting:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Week_No
 R      R       3
```

R-R as default values.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: do you have a numbers table in the database?

Comment: @vkp number of weeks in a table? yes I do have but the structure is week_start and week_end (in the example, 1 and 5 are the values).

Comment: look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/generating-a-range-of-numbers-in-mysql) and create a numbers table..then what you need to do is a `left join` on to that..

Answer (score 3):

You want an `outer join`.  Here is a typical approach:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.col1, 'R') as col1, COALESCE(t1.col2, 'R') as col2,
       n.n as week_no
FROM (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5
      ) n LEFT JOIN
      table1 t1
      ON t1.week_no >= n.n AND week_no <= n.n;
```

Comment: You're too fast for me :)

Comment: he's still asleep though! you both are legends

Comment: But the week numbers are dynamic and not static. Any suggestions. :) (Upvoted your answer though) :)

Comment: @Ronald . . . That is a bit more challenging.  If you have a numbers table -- or even a table with enough rows -- then you can use that to generate the week values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yeah I realized that it's a lot harder than I thought. I already considered the idea of making a weeks table then just left joining it but I have to repeat everything. LOL.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to check the data type in each column that you will insert to your table or to your array.