# Query to find time window between visits

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm creating a small app to register visits and I've got stuck on finding free time windows between visits.

There are two tables, this is a simplified structure:

> working_hours 
>   - start_time 
>   - end_time
>
> visit 
>   - start_time 
>   - end_time 
>   - visit_status

visits_status with value "2" are cancelled visits so we do not include them

Now small example:

Employee has his own working hours with breaks included, for example:

```
| start_time          | end_time            |
| 2018-12-29 08:00:00 | 2018-12-29 12:00:00 |
| 2018-12-29 12:30:00 | 2018-12-29 16:00:00 |
```

There are already visits registered in app, they may have different durations. Visit times have got included break so next visit can start right after . Let's say we have visits like those:

```
| start_time          | end_time            | visit_status |
| 2018-12-29 08:00:00 | 2018-12-29 08:30:00 | 1            |
| 2018-12-29 09:00:00 | 2018-12-29 10:00:00 | 1            |
| 2018-12-29 10:00:00 | 2018-12-29 10:40:00 | 1            |
| 2018-12-29 10:40:00 | 2018-12-29 11:10:00 | 2            |
| 2018-12-29 11:10:00 | 2018-12-29 11:40:00 | 0            |
| 2018-12-29 12:30:00 | 2018-12-29 13:00:00 | 0            |
| 2018-12-29 13:00:00 | 2018-12-29 14:00:00 | 0            |
| 2018-12-29 15:30:00 | 2018-12-29 16:00:00 | 0            |
```

My goal is to create query that will show me available start times for thirty minutes visit including working hours, In this specified case the result should be this times:

> - 8:30
> - 10:40
> - 14:00
> - 14:30
> - 15:00

Comment: Since it's per employee, can we assume there's something like an emp_id in "working_hours"?  And is it then also in "visits"? And you're basically looking for the gaps in the visits?

Comment: Attribute emp_id is not relevant, we can assume there is one employee. Like I mentioned in description, I would like to find a 30-minutes time window for new visit between already booked visits. There is a visit which ends at 14:00:00, another booked visit starts at 15:30, so I can book a new visit at 3 different times - 14:00, 14:30, 15:00.

Comment: @Kamcik . . . Why couldn't you book at 14:15 or 14:50?

Comment: Wasting time - Between 14:00 and 15:30 you can book three 30-minutes visits, when you book visit at 14:15 you waste time between 14:00 and 14:15 and you can book only two visits (14:15, 14:45 and that's all because next time window is 15:15 and there is not time for 30-minutes visit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look like a straightforward gaps-and-islands problem.

First there's the issue of finding the gaps between the visits that are big enough.
And this means that both the start & end times need to be considered.

Then when those gaps are found, they need to be unfolded in 30 minute intervals.

To unfold the gaps you can link to a number table.
It's best to create a permanent one.
The example below just adds values, to keep it simple for this answer.
But there are other methods. F.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/)

```
create table nums (num int primary key not null);
insert into nums (num) VALUES 
(00),(01),(02),(03),(04),(05),(06),(07),(08),(09),
(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),
(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),
(30),(31),(32),(33),(34),(35),(36),(37),(38),(39),
(40),(41),(42),(43),(44),(45),(46),(47),(48),(49);
```

Then a query like this will work in MySql 5.7

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
 CAST(gaps.start_dt + INTERVAL (nums.num * 30) MINUTE AS TIME) as start_time
FROM
(
  SELECT rnk, MIN(prev_dt) as start_dt, MIN(start_dt) as end_dt
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
    start_time AS start_dt, 
    end_time as end_dt, 
    @prev_dt as prev_dt,
    -- DATE(@prev_dt) + INTERVAL (CEIL(TIME_TO_SEC(@prev_dt) / 600) * 600) SECOND as prev_dt,
    (CASE
     WHEN @prev_dt = start_time AND @prev_dt := end_time THEN @rnk
     WHEN @prev_dt := end_time THEN @rnk := @rnk + 1
     END) AS rnk
    FROM visits
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev_dt := null, @rnk := 0) vars
    WHERE visit_status <> 2
    ORDER BY start_time
  ) AS vst
  GROUP BY rnk
  HAVING CAST(MIN(start_dt) AS DATE) = CAST(MIN(prev_dt) AS DATE)
     AND TIMEDIFF(MIN(start_dt), MIN(prev_dt)) >= CAST('00:30' AS TIME)
) gaps
JOIN working_hours wrk 
  ON wrk.start_time <= gaps.start_dt AND wrk.end_time >= gaps.end_dt
JOIN nums
  ON nums.num BETWEEN 0 AND 47
 AND gaps.start_dt + INTERVAL (nums.num * 30) MINUTE < gaps.end_dt;
```

The "vst" sub-query assigns a ranking to the datetimes by using variables.

Then the "gaps" sub-query groups them by that ranking to find the start & end of the gaps.

Then the working_hours is joined.
And the "nums" table is used to unfold the times in 30 minute intervals.

**Result:**

```
start_time
08:30:00
10:40:00
14:00:00
14:30:00
15:00:00
```

You can test it on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c2852ad97f1c3929aa358bf6ee5969dd)*

Comment: This query won't include hours like 14:00, 14:30, 15:00. These are still correct hours to book 30-minutes visit

Comment: @kamcik Now it finds the gaps.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: What should I change to find gaps for 40-minute visit or any other time interval ?

Comment: Look at the 2nd criteria in the HAVING and understand what it does.  About unfolding into intervals, look where num is used.

Comment: Btw, if this were for MySql 8.0 then the calculation via variables could probably be replaced by window functions like LAG & DENSE_RANK.