# how to get rows with time for each minute for last 30 minutes

Tags: mysql

[image: juat like now, i need 30 rows for last 30 minutes]

now returns only one row with current time, I want 30 rows for last 30 minutes for each minute

Comment: Why would you just want to log out the last 30 minutes of time itself? Don't you want to additionally log out some data or events that *occurred* over those 30 minutes?

Comment: I want to display count of records for each minute from a table for last 30minutes  including those missed time, so that i need timestamps

Answer (score 2):

For the count per minute the solution doesn't need the sequence:

```
SELECT MINUTE(timestamp) as m, COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
GROUP BY m
```

Handle gaps of no entries in your application.

The sequence, if there's ever a need:

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ea2e302d3a3a7aa8c699b3bdf7397a6)

This is an extension of a [sequence of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186756/generating-a-range-of-numbers-in-mysql):

```
SELECT
    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL (TENS.SeqValue + ONES.SeqValue) MINUTE) as t
FROM
    (
    SELECT 0  SeqValue
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9
    ) ONES
CROSS JOIN
    (
    SELECT 0 SeqValue
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 10
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 20
    ) TENS
ORDER BY t DESC
```

MariaDB since 10.0 has a [sequence storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/) for a shorter solution:

```
SELECT
    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL seq MINUTE) as t
FROM seq_0_to_30
ORDER BY t DESC
```

Comment: Thak you so much @danblack , the 2nd query works fine, could tell me how can I get only Hours &minutes (H:i)  only from the 2nd query.

Comment: [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Hi @danblack , the seq is not working in some mysql servers, any other way please ...

Comment: I provided a with and without option there. If the first option is "not working" ask a question and provide a meaningful error message or unexpected results along with the MYSQL version.